# KeyDown responding differently for separate textBoxes

Tags: c#, events, textbox, keydown

If it's strange its going to happen to me.

I'm writing a C# Windows Form application (VS 2010) comprised of multiple textboxes as well as multiple labels for them all.  Except for Textbox names the actions are all the same (copied and pasted then the proper TextBox name substituted. They all include a TextChange event and a KeyDown event.  The KeyDown event is to catch the Return key and process the data.

The bazaar part is that the first section (region Operating Frequency) works fine. All others never enter the KeyDown event.  I've looked through and compared properties for all TextBoxes and I see no difference.  I've tried moving the sections around to see if it is the order in the code. Nothing changes.  Operating Frequency always works. Nothing else does. I've tried just about everything I can think of.  I've even tried going from KeyDown to KeyUp with no difference;

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the code.  I've only included the first 2 textboxes as the rest are essentially the same.

```
    // Constants
    public static readonly double rad = Math.PI / 180, DEG = 180 / Math.PI;   // PI to RAD
    public const double solM = 299792458;            // Speed of light in meters/sec
    public const double solMm = solM / 1000;         // Speed of light in mega meters/sec
    public const double solFt = 983571056.43;       // Speed of light in feet/sec
    public const double ft2mtr = 0.3048;               // Convert Feet to Meters

    // Parameters
    public static double D = 60;                            // Loop diameter
    public static double C = D*Math.PI;                  // Loop Circumfrence
    public static double conductorD = 0.375;          // Conductor diameter
    public static double RL = 0;                            // Added loss resistance 
    public static double xmitP = 25;                      // RF xmitter power
    public static double freq = 14.1;                     // Frequence


    public MagLoopAntenna()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Start off with some default parameter values
        tbFreq.Text = "14.1";                        // Target Frequency
        tbLoopDia.Text = "60";                      // Antenna Loop Diameter
        tbUnitsLoopDia.Text = "in";             
        tbConductorDia.Text = "0.5";             // Conductor Diameter
        tbUnitsConductorDia.Text = "in";        // Conductor Diameter Units
        tbAddedLossR.Text = "0";                 // Added Loss in ohms
        tbRfPower.Text = "25";                     // RF Power in Watts
    }

    private bool nonNumberEntered = false;  // Command Key Flag

    #region Operating Frequency
    private void tbFreq_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int test;
        test = 0;           // place for breakpoint
    }
    private void tbFreq_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
        // Initialize the flag to false.
        nonNumberEntered = false;
        // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard.
        if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
       {
            // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad.
            if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
            {
                // Determine whether the keystroke is a backspace.
                if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
                {
                    // A non-numerical keystroke was pressed.
                    // Set the flag to true and evaluate in KeyPress event.
                    nonNumberEntered = true;
                }

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
               {
                   // Note: may want calculate everything at this point.
                   // We got here now move on to the next textbox 
                   freq = Convert.ToDouble(tbFreq.Text);
                   tbLoopDia.Focus();
                }
            }
         }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Loop Diameter
    private void tbLoopDia_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int test;
        test = 0;   // Just a place to put a breakpoint
    }
    private void tbLoopDia_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the flag to false.
        nonNumberEntered = false;
        // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard.
        if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
        {
            // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad.
            if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
            {
                // Determine whether the keystroke is a backspace.
                if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
                {
                    // A non-numerical keystroke was pressed.
                    // Set the flag to true and evaluate in KeyPress event.
                    nonNumberEntered = true;
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    int gothere;
                    gothere = 1;        // Just for a breakpoint

                    // Note: may want calculate everything at this point.
                    // We got here now move on to the next textbox 
                    //tbConductorDia.Focus();          // will implement this once its' working   
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aren't there some additional tags you can add besides just "keydown" ?

Comment: "copied and pasted" surely caused that problem.  That made you forget to subscribe the event(s) for those other controls.  You don't *have* to use the designer to subscribe an event, writing a single line of code in the form constructor is fine as well.

Comment: Hans, I suspect you are dead nuts on.  I decided to start fresh to avoid any overlooked steps.  At the moment I have one textbox with TextChange and KeyDown events and I can't even get that KeyDown event to trigger.  I think I need to do some more reading and get the basic KeyDown event straight before continuing on.  I will definitely let you know how it works out.

Comment: Well, you did nail it.  Thank you so much.  I went back to my original code.  I actually had to go into the designer and put it in there. Thank you so much.  I may not go bald after all :)